# Insert relational data across multiple tables with condition and default value from flat csv file

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have a csv file with data: `provider_id,name,fallback_name`

I also have 3 MySQL tables

`users`

```
| id  | provider_id |
| --- | ----------- |
| 1   | a           |
| 2   | b           |
| 3   | c           |
```

`logins`

```
| id  | provider | provider_id | user_id |
| --- | -------- | ----------- | ------- |
| 1   | default  | a           | 1       |
| 2   | default  | b           | 2       |
```

`profiles`

```
| id  | name | fallback_name | user_id |
| --- | ---- | ------------- | ------- |
| 1   | test | null          | 1       |
| 2   | null | hello         | 2       |
```

What I want to do is insert data for every csv row, let's say one row looks like:
`provider_id,name,fallback_name` > `c,null,test2`. Given this row, I want to do the following:

- In `logins` table, insert `provider_id` and `user_id` where `users.provider_id` = `provider_id`, also set `provider` to "default"
- In `profiles` table, insert `name` if `fallback_name` is null, otherwise insert `name` and `user_id` where `users.provider_id` = `provider_id`

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/ I could only find examples for a single table and most examples only cover basic use cases, hence this question

Comment: You will have to write some code

Comment: I tried.. I can't seem to select what columns I want to insert which causes me to be stuck already when trying to insert in just the logins table

Comment: In what language did you write code

Comment: I would like to do it in SQL if that is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, load your CSV data into a table.  You can throw it away later if you want.  Let's call it `T`.  Then:

> In logins table, insert provider_id and user_id where users.provider_id = provider_id, also set provider to "default"

```
insert into logins ( provider_id, user_id )
select T.provider_id, 'default'
from T join users 
on T.provider_id = users.provider_id
```

Repeat for other tables.

If experience is any guide, you'll have to guard against existing occurrences of `provider_id` in the target table, so:

```
insert into logins ( provider_id, user_id )
select T.provider_id, 'default'
from T join users 
on T.provider_id = users.provider_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    select 1
    from logins 
    where provider_id = T.provider_id
)
```